# How to get selection text and position in google docs by chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want to create an extension like [textcortex](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/textcortex-personal-ai-as/hahkojdegblcccihngmgndhdfheheofe), [wordtune](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wordtune-generative-ai-pr/nllcnknpjnininklegdoijpljgdjkijc) or [grammarly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-grammar-checker/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen). I mean I want develop an extension that when user cursor be in an editable box appear a box or icon beside the selected text (like google docs editable doc, you can check these extension on it) and also can replace selected text, can anyone help me? I did not find any article about it

I check a lot of articles but can't find anything about that because google docs now use canvas not dom elements

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.